# Is the isdst field used at all by os.time()?

Tags: datetime, lua, dst, datetimeoffset

The output of `os.date("*t")`has a `isdst` field in it, and you can specify it in your input to os.time. Maybe I'm being stupid, but I can't see it being used by os.time at all:

```
> print(os.time{year=2016, month=3, day=29, hour=9,min=10,sec=10,isdst=1})
1459235410
> print(os.time{year=2016, month=3, day=29, hour=9,min=10,sec=10,isdst=0})
1459235410
> print(os.time{year=2016, month=6, day=29, hour=9,min=10,sec=10,isdst=0})
1467184210
> print(os.time{year=2016, month=6, day=29, hour=9,min=10,sec=10,isdst=1})
1467184210
```

You seem to get the same Epoch time representation regardless of your specification of `isdst`. So, is it safe to ignore this field?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `isdst` field is a boolean, not number. Note that anything that's not `false` or `nil` are considered truthy, including `0`.

To set `isdst` to `false`, try

```
print(os.time{year=2016, month=6, day=29, hour=9, min=10, sec=10, isdst=false})
```

The default value for `isdst` field is `nil`, so this works as well:

```
print(os.time{year=2016, month=6, day=29, hour=9, min=10, sec=10})
```

Comment: That's it! Thanks! Sorry, Lua is too new to me to be able to throw away assumptions that I am used to.